# React: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'searchState.events.map')

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to retrieve data from an endpoint and display it as a sidebar on a page. This is th epurpose of the file `WikiOngoingEvents`. However on attempting to click on one of the values rendered by `return` at the end of the file I get the below error.

However, I simply can't figure out what is 'wrong' with line 78. This worked absolutely fine in its previous incarnation without the new map section

## Error Title and Details

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'searchState.events.map')
WikiOngoingEvents
src/components/wikireferencegroup/WikiOngoingEvents.js:78
```

```
  75 | <div className="div-right">
  76 |   <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
  77 |     <Card.Header className="small">Ongoing Events</Card.Header>
> 78 |     <ListGroup variant="flush">
  79 | ^
  80 |     {searchState.events.map(theEvent => (
  81 |           <ListGroup.Item className="small"><a onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, theEvent.url)}>{theEvent.title}</a></ListGroup.Item>
```

## On load searchState.events content

[image]

## On Click searchState.events content

`undefined`

## Previous Return contents

```
return (
  <>
    <div className="div-right">
      <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
        <Card.Header className="small">Disasters</Card.Header>
        <ListGroup variant="flush">
          <ListGroup.Item className="small">
            <a
              onClick={(event) =>
                handleClick(
                  event,
                  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic"
                )
              }
            >
              COVID-19 Pandemic
            </a>
          </ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item className="small">
            <a
              onClick={(event) =>
                handleClick(
                  event,
                  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020–21_European_windstorm_season"
                )
              }
            >
              2020-2021 Euopean Windstorm Season
            </a>
          </ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item className="small">
            <a
              onClick={(event) =>
                handleClick(
                  event,
                  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020–2021_H5N8_outbreak"
                )
              }
            >
              2020-20221 H5N8 outbreak
            </a>
          </ListGroup.Item>
        </ListGroup>
      </Card>
      <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
        <Card.Header className="small">Politics</Card.Header>
        <ListGroup variant="flush">
          <ListGroup.Item className="small">
            <a
              onClick={(event) =>
                handleClick(
                  event,
                  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghan_peace_process"
                )
              }
            >
              Afghan Peace Process
            </a>
          </ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item className="small">
            <a
              onClick={(event) =>
                handleClick(
                  event,
                  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018–2021_Arab_protests"
                )
              }
            >
              Arab Protests
            </a>
          </ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item className="small">
            <a
              onClick={(event) =>
                handleClick(
                  event,
                  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020–2021_Belarusian_protests"
                )
              }
            >
              Belarusian Protests
            </a>
          </ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item className="small">
            <a
              onClick={(event) =>
                handleClick(
                  event,
                  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Brazilian_protests"
                )
              }
            >
              Brazilian Protests
            </a>
          </ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item className="small">
            <a
              onClick={(event) =>
                handleClick(
                  event,
                  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Colombian_protests"
                )
              }
            >
              Colombian Tax Reform Protests
            </a>
          </ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item className="small">
            <a
              onClick={(event) =>
                handleClick(
                  event,
                  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Cuban_protests"
                )
              }
            >
              Cuban Protests
            </a>
          </ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item className="small">
            <a
              onClick={(event) =>
                handleClick(
                  event,
                  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Withdrawal_of_United_States_troops_from_Afghanistan_(2020–2021)"
                )
              }
            >
              Withdrawal of US troops from Afghanistan
            </a>
          </ListGroup.Item>
        </ListGroup>
      </Card>
    </div>
  </>
);
```

## Current WikiOngoingEvents file

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { useContext, useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup'
import {SearchContext} from "../../contexts/SearchContext"
import "../../App.css"
import { getEvents } from '../../components/search/requests';



export function WikiOngoingEvents() {


  const {searchState, setSearchState, filterState, setFilters} = useContext(SearchContext);

  useEffect(() => {

          const events = getEvents().then(response => {
            setSearchState({events:response});
            })
           },[])

  const handleClick = (event, option) => {
      setFilters({languageFilter:"",
                  typeFilter:""
                  })
            setSearchState({searchCriteria:option})

      event.preventDefault();
      event.persist();

      const fetchReferences = async (option) => {
                console.log(option);
        fetch('http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/search/', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            url: option
            }),
          headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
          
        }).then(response => {
                return response.json();
        }).then(json => {
          setSearchState({
            headers:json.headers,
            references:json.references,
            events:json.events
          })
        });}

      fetchReferences(option);

  }

    const ongoingEvents = searchState.events;
    return (
      <>
      <div className="div-right">
        <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
          <Card.Header className="small">Ongoing Events</Card.Header>
          <ListGroup variant="flush">

          {searchState.events.map(theEvent => (
                <ListGroup.Item className="small"><a onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, theEvent.url)}>{theEvent.title}</a></ListGroup.Item>
          ))}

          </ListGroup>
        </Card>
      </div>
      </>
    );

}
export default WikiOngoingEvents;
```

Comment: What is the exact value of `searchState.events` at the point this error occurs?

Comment: @DBS it's a little more nuanced. issue updated. On load the values are retrieved. However on clicking the `searchState.events` are set as `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **searchState** object or **events** array may be resulting in undefined that is why you are facing the issue

Try this

```
{searchState?.events?.map(theEvent => (
   <ListGroup.Item className="small"><a onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, theEvent.url)}>{theEvent.title}</a></ListGroup.Item>
))}
```

In the above snippet your list item will only get rendered if **searchState** and events are not null